# AppFabric removes objects for no reason?

Tags: c#, .net, cloud, appfabric

I have an appfabric server, it has one cache with the name Orders and two regions, Orders and TestOrders. Production retrieves from "Orders" and test code retrieves from TestOrders obviously.
Production has been running fine for over a year now and now Im testing some new functionality with the TestOrders region.
It works for a while, orders are retrieved as normal but suddenly nothing is retrieved anymore, empty results.
IsExirable is false for the cache and TTL is 10 minutes so that cant be it (right?)

Anyone knows what to do? I have zero clue what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, the last programmer built in an override for the TTL of objects which was 15 minutes:

```
TimeSpan ttl = _useTTLOverride ? 
new TimeSpan(0, _ttlOverrideMinutes, 0) : order.RetainDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

mCache.Add(preOrder.orderId.ToString(), order, ttl, tags, _regionName);
```